# UPX Unpacking tool

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, tools, unpacking, upx

Firstly, thank you for your answer.

What is the best unpacking tool to use to unpack - UPX 0.89.6 - 1.02 / 1.05 - 1.24 ->[Overlay]    could you please provide a link so i can obtain as such.

Thank you.

Comment: UPX is open source at https://github.com/upx/upx Checkout any version and build it.

Answer (score 3):

upx itself unpacks binaries. Pass the `-d` option on the command line.

Example on a linux box

```bash
$ file exa
exa: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
$ xxd exa | grep UPX
000000e0: 1000 0000 0000 0000 a8aa 40f7 5550 5821  ..........@.UPX!
000a09c0: 6520 5550 5820 6578 6563 7574 6162 6c65  e UPX executable
000a09f0: 3a20 5550 5820 332e 3934 2043 6f70 7972  : UPX 3.94 Copyr
000a0a10: 3137 2074 6865 2055 5058 2054 6561 6d2e  17 the UPX Team.
000a0c70: 1485 d275 1581 fe55 5058 2175 115e 7d00  ...u...UPX!u.^}.
001142d0: 5058 2100 0000 0000 5550 5821 0d16 0807  PX!.....UPX!....
$ upx -d exa
                       Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
                          Copyright (C) 1996 - 2017
UPX 3.94        Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   May 12th 2017

        File size         Ratio      Format      Name
   --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
   3338040 <-   1131260   33.89%   linux/amd64   exa

Unpacked 1 file.
$ file exa
exa: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a1c771fd094e61d2d8fbdab6b688141bfb8b6e30, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

If the UPX header was intentionally broken after packing, you can give a try to this tool to restore it : https://github.com/NozomiNetworks/upx-recovery-tool

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. NB: This helps only for ELF files, so probably won't help for Windows (PE files).